# iterate over a df and multiply the values by the values of another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

My **df1** looks like this:It contains 3 unique project `id`.The `date` starts on `01-01-22` and ends on `01-12-28`

| id | date | p50 | p90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apv1 | 01-01-22 | 1000 | 1000 |
| apv2 | 01-01-22 | 1000 | 1000 |
| tsso | 01-01-22 | 1202 | 2005 |
| apv1 | 01-02-22 | 1000 | 2000 |
| apv2 | 01-02-22 | 1400 | 5000 |
| tsso | 01-02-22 | 200 | 1000 |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |
| apv1 | 01-11-28 | 305 | 400 |
| apv2 | 01-11-28 | 300 | 200 |
| tsso | 01-11-28 | 250 | 499 |
| apv1 | 01-12-28 | 100 | 290 |
| apv2 | 01-12-28 | 145 | 650 |
| tsso | 01-12-28 | 299 | 179 |

**df2** looks like this:

| mth | month | pct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | january | 0.042 |
| 02 | febuary | 0.055 |
| 03 | march | 0.089 |
| 04 | april | 0.097 |
| 05 | may | 0.10 |
| 06 | june | 0.11 |
| 07 | july | 0.127 |
| 08 | august | 0.114 |
| 09 | sept | 0.091 |
| 10 | oct | 0.068 |
| 11 | nov | 0.043 |
| 12 | dec | 0.038 |

I want to multiply each value `p50` of **df1** by the value `pct` of **df2** with `mth` or `month` value equals to the month of the `date` in **df1**. Similarly for `p90`.

The Final **df** should look like this:

| id | date | p50 | p90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apv1 | 01-01-22 | 1000*0.042 | 1000*0.042 |
| apv2 | 01-01-22 | 1000*0.042 | 1000*0.042 |
| tsso | 01-01-22 | 1202*0.042 | 2005*0.042 |
| apv1 | 01-02-22 | 1000*0.055 | 2000*0.055 |
| apv2 | 01-02-22 | 1400*0.055 | 5000*0.055 |
| tsso | 01-02-22 | 200*0.055 | 1000*0.055 |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |
| apv1 | 01-11-28 | 305*0.043 | 400*0.043 |
| apv2 | 01-11-28 | 300*0.043 | 200*0.043 |
| tsso | 01-11-28 | 250*0.043 | 499*0.043 |
| apv1 | 01-12-28 | 100*0.038 | 290*0.038 |
| apv2 | 01-12-28 | 145*0.038 | 650*0.038 |
| tsso | 01-12-28 | 299*0.038 | 179*0.038 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `map` to modify you data in place:

```
s = df2.set_index('mth')['pct']
pct = pd.to_datetime(df1['date']).dt.strftime('%m').map(s)

df1[['p50', 'p90']] *= pct
```

Comment: you might be missing something. I am getting an error that both dataframe don't have same length.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: I found what is wrong. I changed df1[['p50', 'p90']] *= pct to df1['p50']*=pct and df1['p90']*=pct. it works

Answer (score 1):

Simply `assign` month column using the date column. Then `merge` both data frames by month. Finally, run multiplication with needed columns:

```py
final_df = (
    df1.assign(mth = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x["date"]).dt.strftime("%m"))
       .merge(df2, on="mth")
       .assign(
           p50 = lambda x: x["p50"].mul(x["pct"]),
           p90 = lambda x: x["p90"].mul(x["pct"])
       )
)
```